# Looking for a Mac system icon - Finder PDF Preview icon

Tags: mac, icons

Looking for the .icns file for the Finder PDF Preview icon. Can anyone tell me where it is located?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a pdf.icns file in the package contents of the Preview.app.

Go to the Preview.app application in the Applications folder. Right click and 'Show Package Contents'. The pdf.icns file can be found here:

> /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/Resources/pdf.icns

It doesn't look like the image you posted above however. At least not on OSX El Capitan (10.11.5)